# Python: Canvas Hotkey bindings don't work with keys

Tags: python, canvas, binding, key

My Problem today is, that I don't get Canvas hotkeys bindings working.. Working example with Mousebutton:

```
def abc(event):
    print("abc")
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root)
canv.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canv.bind("<Button-1>", abc)
root.mainloop()
```

Not working with "a" letter:

```
def abc(event):
    print("abc")
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root)
canv.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canv.bind("a", abc)
root.mainloop()
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the `Canvas` widget doesn't receive focus when you click on it, so key press events don't get executed. Consider binding your keyboard shortcuts to the root instead.

```
def abc(event):
    print("abc")
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root)
canv.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
root.bind("a", abc)
root.mainloop()
```